# Why I'm getting only two lines using LineRenderer and not three lines to create a triangle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[3] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 1, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 0) };
        DrawTriangle(positions);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void DrawTriangle(Vector3[] vertexPositions)
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 3;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(vertexPositions);
    }
}
```

The LineRenderer component in the Inspector :

[image: LineRenderer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only 3 positions in your array.

Line 1 is drawn from 0,0,0 to -1,1,0
then line 2 is drawn from -1,1,0 to 1,1,0.

at this point you have no more positions to draw to.

Essentially you need 2 positions to draw a line. Line renderer draw from a to b, b to c, c to d etc...

You could also check the loop boolean so the line renderer draws a final line from last point to first point thus making a triangle with 3 positions.

Comment: Right I found the Loop toggle already a minute ago but if I wanted to make it without the Loop toggle what is the 4 line position that I need ? Tried some but can't find.

Comment: your first position (0,0,0) so the last line drawn is from 1,1,0 to 0,0,0 thus making the triangle.